# BigQuery error transferring csv from cloud storage

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table in bigquery transferring a csv from google storage. This csv has 30 million rows and I get these errors, for example:

"Error while reading data, error message: Too many values in row starting at position: 254333656. Found 4 column(s) while expected 3"

"Error while reading data, error message: Too many values in row starting at position: 254312106. Found 4 column(s) while expected 3."

This is embarrassing, I do not have all these rows in my csv. It found an error at rows 250 million. How is it possible??

Thank you

Comment: can you check that the csv file is in UTF-8, or can you provide a bit more details on the loading process, please?

Comment: Yes, the file is UTF-8. This is the lin from which I downloaded the csv file https://zenodo.org/record/2539424 it is the "itwiki.wikilink_graph.2018-03-01.csv.gz"
 file. It is impossible for me to open it on my laptop on libreoffice, I just scanned a bit through it with a text editor. It has four columns, describing Wikipedia pages and link for each page. Do you think the problem could be that some cells contain quotations mark? I really really do not know which could be the problem

Comment: yes, the quotation marks can be an issue. BTW, I think that the position number you mentioned - is not a row number but a character (or byte) number from the beginning of the file.

Comment: You can't open a file, but you can perform a head on linux (on Cloud Shell for example). Can you paste the 3 first line (head -3 <filename>) to show us the structure? In addition, the exact command (or configuration) that you perform to ingest your csv file in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The error states there is an issue at `position` 254333656, and not `row`.

It means that the error is located 254333656 characters away from the beginning of the file (which makes debugging quite difficult).

In order to fix your issue you can:

- check that your header indeed has 4 columns (BQ seems to expect 3 columns, but you say you expect 4)
- maybe try the flag --allow_jagged_row=true into your bq load statement.